# Multi data center nodes seed list

Tags: cassandra, datastax

I have build a 3 node cluster in US and currently adding another 3 nodes in singapore. I saw in cassandra documentation that if new node is being added then in its yaml file its ipaddress should not be present in the seeds list. I wanted to have 2 seeds from the singapore region and so I added same ( 2 us ip address and 2 singapore addres) in seeds list. My question is can i add the ip  address for new singapore node in its seeds list before i start the server and make it join the cluster? ( I also have the US seeds added in it, i.e,. us 2 and singapore 2 ). THanks for the information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can add the new seed nodes before starting them. As new nodes come up, they will initially use the existing (us) seed nodes before the new nodes are available.